# Passing data from view model to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am beginner in ASP.NET Core, I'm making car rental site, and on one view I have view model that contains two properties I have first model which contains data about car and second model that contains data about reservation.

First model Car:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Model { get; set; }

    public string Manufacturer { get; set; }

    public Transmission Transmission { get; set; }

    public Fuel Fuel { get; set; }

    public string ImageThumbnailUrl { get; set; }

    public int DoorNumber { get; set; }

    public int Passangers { get; set; }

    public decimal Price { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }

    public bool Available { get; set; }

    public Location CurrentLocation { get; set; }
}
```

And second model Reservation:

```
public class Reservation
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public int CarId { get; set; } 

    public Location PickUpLocation { get; set; }

    public Location ReturnLocation { get; set; }

    public DateTime PickUpDate { get; set; }

    public DateTime ReturnDate { get; set; }
}
```

The view contains CarReservationViewModel:

```
public class CarReservationViewModel
{
    public Car Car { get; set; }

    public Reservation Reservation { get; set; }
}
```

View looks like:

```
@model CarReservationViewModel
<form asp-action="MakeReservation" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="container detail">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h2>@Model.Car.Manufacturer  @Model.Car.Model</h2>
                <h4>Rent a @Model.Car.Manufacturer  @Model.Car.Model</h4>
                <p>
                    @Html.Raw(@Model.Car.LongDescription)
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img class="car-image" src="@Url.Content(@Model.Car.ImageThumbnailUrl)" alt="" />
                <div class="pricing primary-background">
                    <span class="amount">
                        Price from @Model.Car.Price EUR
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="row center-subrow">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group align-items">
                            <label class="col-md-6" asp-for="@Model.Reservation.PickUpLocation"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select class="col-md-4 form-control" asp-for="@Model.Reservation.PickUpLocation" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<Location>().OrderBy(l =>l.Text)"></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group align-items">
                            <label class="col-md-6" asp-for="@Model.Reservation.ReturnLocation"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <select class="col-md-4 form-control" asp-for="@Model.Reservation.ReturnLocation" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<Location>().OrderBy(l =>l.Text)"></select>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row center-subrow">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group align-items">
                            <label class="col-md-6" asp-for="@Model.Reservation.PickUpDate"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="datepicker1" class="col-md-4 form-control datepicker" asp-for="@Model.Reservation.PickUpDate" data-provide="datepicker" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group align-items">
                            <label class="col-md-6" asp-for="@Model.Reservation.ReturnDate"></label>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="datepicker2" class="col-md-4 form-control datepicker" asp-for="@Model.Reservation.ReturnDate" data-provide="datepicker" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="reservation">
                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Car.Id);
                    <input type="submit" class="btn-reservation" value="Make reservation">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Car controller have method Detail and MakeReservation:

```
    public IActionResult Detail(int id)
    {
        var carReservationViewModel = new CarReservationViewModel
        {
            Car = _carRepository.GetCarById(id)
        };
        return View(carReservationViewModel);
    }
```

When I came to Detail method it pass car detail to view, and that view contains form for submitting data about reservation. I have problem when I click on submit button on that form, viewModel Car property is null, but Reservation property have values, can I pass car data back to viewModel.Car property?

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult MakeReservation(CarReservationViewModel viewModel)
    {

        if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var reservation = new Reservation
            {
                CarId = viewModel.Car.Id, //viewModel.Car is null
                PickUpDate = viewModel.Reservation.PickUpDate,
                ReturnDate = viewModel.Reservation.ReturnDate,
                PickUpLocation = viewModel.Reservation.PickUpLocation,
                ReturnLocation = viewModel.Reservation.ReturnLocation
            };

            _reservationRepository.Add(reservation);

        }

        return View();
    }
```

Is it normal to have two model on view one for showing information (Car model) and one for containing data about reservation (Reservation model).

Answer (score 1):

Only controls are transmitted in forms.

Background in [W3C: Forms in HTML documents](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html), especially the chapter on [successful controls.](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.2)

Use `<input/>` of type `hidden` or `@Html.HiddenFor()` to bind the data of `Car` model to the server-side

```
<h2>@Model.Car.Manufacturer  @Model.Car.Model</h2>
<input asp-for="@Model.Car.Manufacturer" hidden />
<input asp-for="@Model.Car.Model" hidden />

//or 
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Car.Manufacturer);
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Car.Model);
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but if you have experience in this can you answer on this: 
Is it normal to have two model on view one for showing information (Car model) and one for containing data about reservation (Reservation model)?

Comment: @Anve, _"Is it normal to have two model on view one for showing information "_ . It is not normal, the ViewModel is the better choice.

Answer (score 0):

*"Is it normal to have two model on view one for showing information (Car model) and one for containing data about reservation (Reservation model)."* :

No, it is not normal. Instead, you can combine multiple entities into a `ViewModel` and pass this `ViewModel` to the `View`.

On the other hand, you can try the following method to combine entities or models:

***ViewModel:***

```
public class GroupViewModel
{       
    //Foreign key for Lab
    public int LabId { get; set; }
 
    //Foreign key for Term
    public int TermId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Labs { get; set; }
 
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Terms { get; set; } 
}
```

***Controller:***

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new GroupViewModel
    {
        // Hard coded for demo. You can replace with real data from dB
        var model = new GroupViewModel();
 
        Labs = repository.Labs.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.Id.ToString(),
            Text = c.Name
        }),
        Terms = repository.Terms.Select(c => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.Id.ToString(),
            Text = c.Name
        })
    };
    return PartialView("_Create", model);
}
```